# How do I grep the lines based on '.' (dot)?

Tags: text-processing, grep

Suppose I've `file` with the following contents:

```
123
251
7.8
951
```

Now I want to `grep` the lines having `.` I've tried:

```
$ cat file | grep .
123
251
7.8
951
```

```
$ cat file | grep '.'
123
251
7.8
951
```

But it isn't working as expected. So, How do I `grep` string based on `.`?

Additional Info:

```
$ grep --version | line
grep (GNU grep) 2.16
```

Comment: @JeffSchaller This is not about Bash's behaviour of \ or \\

Comment: Agreed, but it's very much about the special behavior of ‘.', which that Q's answers cover.

Comment: Escape the dot: `grep '\.' file`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That result you're getting is because **`.` matches any single character**

- From [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/egrep.1.html) >REGULAR EXPRESSIONS:

  > The fundamental building blocks are the regular expressions that match a single character. Most  characters,
  >      including  all  letters  and  digits,  are regular expressions that match themselves.  **Any meta-character with
  >      special meaning may be quoted by preceding it with a backslash.**
  >
  > **The period . matches any single character.**

  So, `.` is required to be escaped with `\`

  ```
  $ cat file | grep '\.'
  7.8
  ```

  Note that here `\.` should be quoted with `'`.
- Another way is to use **`-F, --fixed-strings`** option with `grep` or use `fgrep`.

  ```
   -F, --fixed-strings
            Interpret  PATTERN  as  a  list of fixed strings, separated by newlines, any of which is to be matched.
  ```

  Example:

  ```
  $ cat file | grep -F .
  7.8
  ```

  ```
  $ cat file | fgrep .
  7.8
  ```
- Another work-around is to use bracket expression with enclosing a string which is to be matched inside `[` and `]`:

  ```
  $ cat file | grep '[.]'
  7.8
  ```